# Unlocking mulitple bitlocker encrypted devices at system startup

Tags: windows-10, passwords, bitlocker

There are two partitions on the single disk in my Thinkpad, one for Windows 10 Pro (C:), and one for the data (D:). I'm thinking about enrcypting *both* disks using windows bitlocker.

All documentation I've found so far seems to tell me:

- Windows will ask for the system drives's password at boot time.
- Windows will ask for the data drive's password upon first access to it.

Is there a way to setup the system, so that Windows will ask only once for the single password to unlock *both* drives (assuming the passwords are identical, of course)?

**Update 1**
It was not clear from my initial question that I want the system to boot *only* when the (single) password was correctly entered.

Comment: My suggestion is stored the key to the system disk within  TPM and automatically mount the data driver by storing the password to it.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If the systems disk's (drive C:) bitlocker password is saved to the TPM, will I still be prompted for it a boot time? And what about the data drives password? Will that also be taken from the TPM? Note: I do want to be prompted for a password.

Comment: "will I still be prompted for it a boot time?" - No; "Will that also be taken from the TPM?" - Only one BitLocker key can be stored in the TPM.  You only want a single password prompt, I provide an option, to accomplish that goal in securely

Answer (score 0):

I advise against full-disk encryption that includes Windows.
The reason is that a corrupted Windows partition can be repaired,
but a corrupted bitlocked full-disk is just a total lose of data.
In case of a Bitlocker problem, having a functional Windows may
be useful.

If your computer has TPM of at least level 1.2, see the article
[How does BitLocker work without asking for a password?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-BitLocker-work-without-asking-for-a-password)

> BitLocker is a feature in Windows that allows users to encrypt their
> hard drive and protect their data with a password or other
> authentication methods. It is designed to prevent unauthorized access
> to the data on the hard drive, even if the physical drive is removed
> from the computer and connected to another device.
>
> However, BitLocker can also be configured to work without asking for a
> password in certain scenarios. This can be done by using a Trusted
> Platform Module (TPM) chip on the computer, which is a hardware
> security device that stores and manages the encryption keys for
> BitLocker.
>
> When BitLocker is configured to work with a TPM chip, the encryption
> keys are stored securely on the chip, and the system can automatically
> unlock the hard drive when the computer is booted up. This means that
> the user does not have to enter a password to access their data, as
> the TPM chip handles the authentication process.
>
> However, it is important to note that this type of configuration is
> only recommended for trusted computers, as it may compromise the
> security of the data if the computer is stolen or accessed by
> unauthorized users. It is also important to regularly update the TPM
> firmware and ensure that the TPM chip is properly configured and
> functioning correctly.
>
> The key to unlock the drive is stored within the TPM security module
> on the motherboard and is only released if the TPM’s measurements of
> the system all return the expected values. Changing certain aspects of
> the machine since the last boot, such as a BIOS upgrade, can cause the
> TPM to not release the key and force the user to provide the recovery
> key. Once the system is booted successfully the measurements are
> generally updated automatically for future boots. Without a TPM,
> another authentication mechanism such as a user-entered PIN or storage
> of the key on a removable USB drive is required.

Useful reference :
[BitLocker FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/data-protection/bitlocker/faq).

Comment: `a corrupted bitlocked partition is just a total lose of data` it may be true, but how is that an argument for `I advise against encrypting the Windows partition`? (Or do your think people should just avoid encryption in general?)

Comment: @TomYan: I have nothing against bitlocked data partitions, but I'm strongly for keeping a functional non-encrypted Windows partition. In several full-disk Bitlocker posts I have encountered here, it would have (perhaps) helped with the corruption problem, instead of giving the answer that the disk was inaccessible and all is lost. I paraphrased my answer to mean only full-disk encryption that includes Windows.

Comment: The problem is, if one should avoid encryption (of anything) because it could lead to total loss of data, then one shouldn't encrypt "data partitions" either, because having a working Windows does not eliminate the "risk" anyway. (I mean, you can have backup, you can have rescue drive, you can have an extra Windows installation, but it's illogical to suggest that one should avoid encrypting the Windows partition, because total loss of data on the "data partitions" would be way more disastrous.)

Comment: @TomYan: Agreed although with a somewhat different opinion. In most cases I advise users of Bitlocker to keep good backups. Bitlocker is safe from hacking, but a small corruption of disk data can lose the whole data. It's a common problem also to Veracrypt, although there the protection against disk corruption is perhaps somewhat better than Bitlocker.